# Mirror 3 displays on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 21.10

Is it possible to mirror all my 3 connected displays on Ubuntu 21.10?

(The Display settings work fine up until 2 displays, the problem is that there is no Mirror option anymore if I connect the third display.)

I'd like to keep this setting after restarts and even show the login screen on all 3 displays.
(If it's not possible than show login on primary, and switch to mirrored after login.)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will show a dialog to mirror or join displays. This works with more than 2 monitors even though the option disappears in settings.